# Loop for lines and for position of lines

Tags: vhdl

I want to have a loop that runs the all lines of my code and also that runs every position of all lines.
My problem is in selecting the line that the loop will run, and I want to have simple way to do it without making to write every single line one-by-one, cause the final code will have 66 lines to scan.

Hope you can help me.

Entity of this code will have 66 lines, but I'm just testing it this 10 lines right now:

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
use ieee.numeric_std.all;  

 entity lshift is  
  port( RED_Buffer1 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    RED_Buffer2 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    RED_Buffer3 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    RED_Buffer4 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    RED_Buffer5 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    IR_Buffer1 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    IR_Buffer2 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    IR_Buffer3 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    IR_Buffer4 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    IR_Buffer5 : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

    output : out bit_vector(1 downto 0)); 
 end lshift;
```

What I have done so far but with no success:

ARCHITECTURE main OF lshift IS
SIGNAL condition1: boolean;
signal valor : std_ulogic;

BEGIN

```
PROCESS(IR_Buffer5)
    BEGIN
        FOR I IN 1 TO 5 LOOP
            FOR J IN 1 TO 5 LOOP
                CONSTANT linha_cond : string(1 to 12) := string(("RED_Buffer") && I);
                IF (linha_cond(J) = '1') THEN
                    output <= "01";
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
END PROCESS;
```

END main;

Comment: You are building the name of a variable in your code in another variable and then want the compiler to recognizes the variable name in the source code. I can program in about 14 languages, but none of them allow that construct. VHDL certainly not. Either radical change your input ports. e.g. make it an multi-dimentional array of signals, or do what often needs to be done in HDL: Write your 66 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of this answer is to demonstrate indexing the subelement values of `RED_Buffer1` through `RED_Buffer5`. Without the purpose of the code being revealed this could easily prove to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) question.

While it is possible to organize `RED_Buffer1` through `RED_Buffer5` into a value that can be indexed as shown below, there are other issues as well.

```vhdl
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  

entity lshift is  
    port (
        red_buffer1:    in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        red_buffer2:    in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        red_buffer3:    in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        red_buffer4:    in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        red_buffer5:    in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        ir_buffer1:     in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        ir_buffer2:     in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        ir_buffer3:     in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        ir_buffer4:     in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        ir_buffer5:     in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        output:         out bit_vector (1 downto 0)
    ); 
 end entity lshift;

architecture indexed_array of lshift is 
    signal condition1:  boolean;
    signal valor:       std_ulogic;
    type lbuffer is array (1 to 5) of std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal red_buffer:  lbuffer;
begin
    red_buffer <= (red_buffer1, red_buffer2, red_buffer3, red_buffer4,
                   red_buffer5);       
    process (red_buffer)
    begin
        for i in 1 to 5 loop
            for j in red_buffer'range loop
                if red_buffer(i)(j) = '1' then
                    output <= "01";
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture indexed_array;
```

**How the indexing is implemented here**

A composite type (`lbuffer`) having the requisite number of elements with required element subtype is declared. This is possible because the declarations for ports `RED_Buffer1` through `RED_Buffer5` share a common subtype indication. Assignment to elements of an object of the type `lbuffer` would be compatible, having matching elements between the target and right hand expression.

A signal `red_buffer` with a type mark of `lbuffer` is declared.

A concurrent assignment was made to the signal in a concurrent signal assignment statement in the architecture statement part from an aggregate. The association in the aggregate is positional. It could as easily use named association:

```vhdl
    -- red_buffer <= (red_buffer1, red_buffer2, red_buffer3, red_buffer4,
    --                red_buffer5);
   red_buffer <= (1 => red_buffer1, 2 => red_buffer2, 3 => red_buffer3,
                  4 => red_buffer4, 5 => red_buffer5);
```

The type of the aggregate is taken from context, here the assignment statement where `red_buffer` has the subtype `lbuffer`.

A selected element of the composite `red_buffer` is selected by an index name (`red_buffer(i)`). A subelement of `red_buffer(i)` is selected by use of an indexed name where the name `red_buffer(i)` where 'i`is a constant using 'j` from the inner loop - `red_buffer(i)(j)`.

Note the range of the `j` parameter doesn't match the index range of subtype of the `lbuffer` element subtype here identical to the subtype of `RED_Buffer1` through `RED_Buffer5`. This signifies a further potential semantic issue with the original code, whose purpose isn't made clear here. The only hint present in the original code comes from `linha_cond` where linha means line in Portuguese or Catalan indicating `j` is used to index within a 'line'.

**The original code fails for two reasons**

First an object can't be declared inline in VHDL. The for loop parameter is dynamically elaborated from an implicit declaration, the loop parameter is only visible within the loop statement's sequence of statements. The syntax doesn't allow for additional object declarations.

Second a name for a object declaration is conveyed in an identifier list consisting of one or more identifiers which are lexical elements (lexemes) that cannot be manipulated programmatically.

**Other semantic issues with the question's code**

The assignment to `output` without the passage of time doesn't appear useful.

A process statement is an independently executing concurrent statement wherein the loop statement containing an assignment to the same signal `output` will overwrite the *projected output waveform* for elements of `output` without any intervening passage of time.

There's only one entry in a projected output waveform queue for any particular simulation time. A simulation cycle consists of signal updates followed by the resumption and subsequent suspension of any processes sensitive to signal updates. The purpose is to emulate parallelism in hardware while describing behavior with sequential statements.

Here that would mean `output` would be updated to the value "01" if any of the if statement conditions in the unrolled loops evaluate to TRUE. That's likely not the intended behavior (without more information from the original poster).

Also note there is no `output` assignment to a different value and no default or otherwise assigned value. For synthesis this would represent a hold over delay on `output` until a '1' is first found.

In both cases this refers to an implicit latch for `output`.

This issue with the sample code can't be addressed without knowing how it is supposed to work and the only hint that has been shown here on Stackoverflow to date is by a [question deleted by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55869696/revisions) requiring 10K+ reputation to access (others will see a`Page not found` message, see [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55869696/1)).

Also concepts conveyed from programming or scripting languages don't generally port to Hardware Description Languages which are generally formal notations defined self-referentially (here in IEEE Std 1076, the VHDL Language Reference Manual) requiring inculcation or persistent effort to learn. HDLs generally describe hardware behaviorally and structurally not by programmatic equivalence.